# System.ObjectDisposedException when closing form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application which has a main form (Home screen) and many subforms.

When the subform is closed and called back again from the main form the System.ObjectDisposedException exception occurs.

Below are my screen codes listed :

Home screen code calling the Subform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Application
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {

        private void Businesslogic_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BusinessRules.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

Subform Designer.CS code for disposing objects:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Subform .CS code for the form closing event:

```
bool formClosing false; 
private void BusinessRules_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (formClosing) return;
        e.Cancel = true;
        Timer Tmr = new Timer();
        Tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
        Tmr.Start();
        formClosing = true;
    }

    void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Timer)sender).Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the timer in `BusinessRules_FormClosing`?

Comment: Also, you don't show how you are closing and re-opening the sub-form in any of the code you posted

Comment: Where are you creating `BusinessRules`? I suspect you are creating it once in somewhere like `Home_Load`, then using the same instance every time. Because you are closing the `BusinessRules` form, rather than just hiding it, it is getting disposed and then you are calling `Show()` on the disposed form

Comment: @Rhumborl : Yes I'm creating the BusinessRules in the home form load... Its getting disposed and im calling show () method.... I'm sorry i'm new to this C#... how do I resolve this  ?

Comment: @JasonWatkins : I read that stoping the Timer thread before closing the form would resolv ethis issue.. thats why added the code there in form closing event..... correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: Are you actually creating the Timer in the same method in your real code? Simply Creating and stopping a timer won't solve anything! The advice you read most certainly related to stopping a timer that is already running.

Comment: When a form is closed, it's closed. That's it. If you need data from the controls on the form, read them before closing the form. If you want to show the form again, create a new instance. Are you coming from a Delphi/Visual Basic background?

Comment: You're closing the form, then cancelling that and closing the form again after the tick of a timer. No wonder it's not working. There is simply no point in doing this. Just close the form.

Comment: @Luaan : Yes I'm form VB background..... thanks....so I need to create a new instance if the form is closed...

Comment: If there's some reason that you don't want the form to close, then handle that on your Closing event and set e.cancel = true or false depending on some logic that dictates whether it should close or not, but don't do what you're doing just now with this timer. Terribly prone to error here.

Comment: @ManoDestra:what you mentioned is right i removed the timer code now which has no meaning here...  I want the form to be closed when the user closes the form and opens with new instance when the use calls it back again from the home screen.....

Comment: That's what you usually want to do, yes. If you want to show the same dialog to the user again, you'll just have to hide it rather than closing it - this is useful in some cases, but really, almost all the time just creating a new instance is the most straight-forward way of handling this. Trying to maintain a list of default form instances and handling their hiding etc. is doable, but there's little point most of the time, really. In general, you're trying to keep scope as small as possible - that makes code much easier to reason about.

Comment: In which case, just close or hide the form. And reopen it or show it from the main form as required.

Comment: Yes thanks... Please post this answer as new comment so I can tick the comment....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store the state of the form, simply call the Hide() method and set e.Cancel = true. Then just call Show() on the form variable again to re-open it.

If you don't want to retain the state, simply close the form. And open a fresh instance of the form from your main page.

Comment: Hi... Just a quick question.... How do I create a new instance for the subform everytime when it gets closed X...... ?

Comment: I imagine you already have code for that in your main form? Like `var businessRulesForm = new BusinessRulesForm(); businessRulesForm.Show();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Subform.CS :

```
    private void Subform_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: I know this code which will hide the form... but doesnt close it.... when I click the form again it will open with the values in it's previous session.